# How to take specific element from the first list ,second list and those specific element add into third list[C#]

Tags: c#-4.0

I want to result like below :

List a1=new List(){"a","b","c","d"};

List a2=new List(){"1","2","3"};

Output : a1b2c3d

Please help how to achieve without using inbuilt function.
I am unable to write the code for this.